# Update column from a table with newly generated passwords

Tags: mysql

So I have the code for generating the kind of passwords I want which is

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 6) AS Paswoord
```

How do I make this work for all the 60 rows I already have at once.
I think it might be with Inner Join etc. I have tried some stuff but the all fail.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please: **sorry made a typo** - anyway the above two answers are there to help you :)

```
UPDATE maintable
    SET maintable.column = (SELECT SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 6))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tableName
SET columnName = SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()),1,6)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE USER SET 
PASSWORD = SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND(ID)) FROM 1 FOR 6)
WHERE PASSWORD IS NULL -- or whatever consition matches rows you want to update
```

Comment: Well I adapated everything but it doesn't work :p
BonCodigo's answers works perfectly. thanks anyway :D

Comment: @JohnSmittheeerrs then omit the `WHERE` clause altogether